# Increase the size of each box in path component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

How to increase the size of each box in the path component? I have Used code in the lightning design system to display the path and its color because of the size of the boxes, text in the box is not displayed completely.
Adding inline style didn't help in increasing size.
A piece of the code from the component for reference.

```
 <li class="slds-path__item path_60Days" role="presentation">
  <a aria-selected="true" class="slds-path__link" href="#" id="path-2" role="option" tabindex="-1" onclick = "{!c.handleSelect}"
     data-variablename="60daysNotice">
    <span class="slds-path__stage">
      <img class="slds-icon slds-icon--large" src="/resource/SLDS0121/assets/icons/standard/record.svg" />
      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Stage Complete</span>
    </span>
    <span class="slds-path__title">60 days Notice</span>
  </a>
</li>
```